# DjangoCMS - Render database data to html

Tags: django, django-cms

I'm testing out the DjangoCMS but I cannot understand how to create custom plugins that enable rendering data out of the database.
I'd like to create a plugin that shows all the users for example but I can't understand how to pass the data into the HTML file.
I followed the DJangoCMS documentation to create a custom plugin that shows the guest name, I've already tried to add users = User.objects.all() and then pass it to the render function but I receive an argument exception because the render function does not allow so many arguments, so what's the approach in DJangoCMS?
**models.py**

```
from cms.models.pluginmodel import CMSPlugin
from django.db import models    
class Hello(CMSPlugin):
    guest_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='Guest')
```

**cms_plugins.py**

```
from cms.plugin_base import CMSPluginBase
from cms.plugin_pool import plugin_pool
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Hello

@plugin_pool.register_plugin
class HelloPlugin(CMSPluginBase):
    model = Hello
    name = _("Hello Plugin")
    render_template = "hello_plugin.html"
    cache = False
    def render(self, context, instance, placeholder):
        context = super().render(context, instance, placeholder)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it like this!

```
context = super().render(context, instance, placeholder)   
users = User.objects.all()
context['users'] = users
return context
```